# Onload event on <form> tag

Tags: javascript, forms, onload

I want a JavaScript function to execute when the page loads.

I added an `onload` attribute to my `<form>` tag, but the `alert` is not executed.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<form name=myfm method=post action=quiz.php onload = alert('hello')>
```

Comment: `<form>` has no "onload", nor should it. if you want to run something onload, then put it on the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Moreover, according to https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_onload.asp, HTML tags that support this event are: <body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try adding the `onload` to the `body` tag

```
<body onload="alert('Hello World')">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//  javaScript
window.onload = function{
   alert("loaded");
}


//  jquery
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div-id").click(function(){ 
    alert("the page is loaded");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: An explanation of the problem and your solution would be helpful.

Comment: @showdev Its  self explanatory, window.onload = do something, if i explained it any more then the questioner needs to learn some basic fundamentals before posting questions

Comment: Yes, you've written code to achieve what the OP is suggesting. But that doesn't explain why the OP's code didn't work (namely because the `<form>` tag does not support an `onload` attribute) or why your code solves the issue. Therefore, further explanation would be helpful.

Comment: The only real issue with this post is that the first non-comment line is missing the parenthesis in the function declaration - it should read `...function() {...` - also, the accepted answer does not have the explanation, and I think this is a better approach, as it does not embed JavaScript within HTML, which seems like an antipattern to me.

Comment: Only thing to be careful about - if you include multiple JavaScript files, and more than 1 file has `window.onload = `, those declarations will overwrite each other.  I believe jQuery accounts for this, but don't quote me on that.